# Expandable listview not fit to the whole fragment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-constraintlayout

activity_Main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.efftronics.android.mobilecashflow.Activity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lin_fragment_home"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandible_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null">

    </ExpandableListView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Expandale ListView selected to centre. Please see the image]

In Main activity I set the activity_main.xml. In that main Layout I have included the content_main.xml
In fragment I need to set the Expandablelistview. But it did not set to the whole fragement. It was set to only centre of the fragment.

Please help me. I tried in many ways. But not getting the solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell me in which layout file I need to change?@JaydeepPatel

Comment: In your fragment_frame layout, can you try setting both width and height to 0dp? Instead of wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your frame layout `@+id/fragment_frame` is `wrap_content` for the height and width while also being constrained to all sides. If I were to guess, I would make the height and width `match_parent` and ensure the constraints have absolute constraints.

Comment: `match_parent` should NOT be used inside of ConstraintLayout (GoogleDoc of ConstraintL)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed framelayout width and height to 0dp. Then I got the expandable list to whole fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.efftronics.android.mobilecashflow.Activity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```